# Activity Covering the status bar

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-statusbar

I have two activities MainActivity and SecondActivity. The status bar in main activity is visible but not in second activity. I am not being able to figure out the reason.

I am using DrawerLayout in MainActivity and RelativeLayout in SecondActivity.

MainActivity

[Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYaz9.png)

SecondActivity

[SecondActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP6t6.png)

I have set status bar color to transparent globally in themes.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Use this one
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: No, I am using <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">